# Configuration Settings Strategy

Tags: php

In a CMS I've developed in PHP, I have configuration settings. They are kept in constants. I chose this approach because constants always have global scope, are easy to see in code when following the all caps convention, and can't be accidentally overwritten. It is also my understanding that references to constants are very efficient; is that true?.

There are two subsets of these constants. Some are hard-coded because they have to do with my code or security. Others are stored in a settings table (MySQL) and on initialziation are read into constants.

I'm concerned that the number of these constants is rising and that I might have a conflict with a third-party PHP module that I use in the future.

I'm wondering if there is better way to handle such settings.

The main idea I had was to create one global variable (e.g., $settings), an associative (key-value) array that would correspond one-to-one with the constants I now have. Thus instead of

```
 define('MY_SETTING, 'setting value');
```

I would have

```
 $setting['my_setting'] = 'setting value';
```

There are two ways to access this, of course. The simplest is to reference the $setting array directly, which would require a global statement in every function that accessed settings (and that's at least a majority of them). The other way is to have a single function (e.g., setting('my_setting)) that would reference the global array to return the value. Both are syntactically compact although not as compact as constants.

The final thought I had was to add a constant prefix to every constant in my system. MY_SETTING would become XY_MY_SETTING. This at least reduces the risk of collision.

Are there other approaches that you would recommend? Any comments about what I've done so far?

Thanks.

Additional Info: I decided to run a quick performance test of four methods of access. Results (numbers shown are relative measures):

- Constants: 32
- Direct reference to associative array: 29
- Function call to access associative array: 91
- Get Method for class: 103

Clearly the overhead of dealing with a function or method is high and the difference between constants and array references is negligible.

Comment: Micro-optimizations are the root of all evil.

Comment: @KingCrunch - I don't write original code with optimization in mind but I'm old-fashioned; if I see something that is happening a lot, I like to know how much time it eats. For sites deployed to shared hosting services, it could be important.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a settings class.

Add additional properties as you see fit, and add getter's and setter's for them.

This will keep it separate from the rest of the program, while remaining visible.

Comment: A setting class with constants of your setting attributes will work well.

Comment: The class idea had occurred to me as well but the instantiation won't be global and I will thus need global statements in every function. I was also concerned that the class approach would yield the worst performance.